# Heatmap using R

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to plot heatmap of a matrix by reading data from a csv file.
Here is how the code looks:

```
lda <- read.csv('topic_word_matrix.data',sep=",")
row.names(lda) <- lda$topics
lda <- lda[,2:ncol(lda)]
lda_matrix <- data.matrix(lda)
lda_heatmap <- heatmap(lda_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA,col = cm.colors(256), scale="column", margins=c(5,10))
```

My input file looks like the following:

```
topics,jockin,limited,raining,magnetic,reallamarodom
topic9,0.0,0.0,0.00671140939597,0.0022271714922,0.00234192037471
topic2,0.1,0.0,0.02671140939597,0.0022271714922,0.00234192037471
```

I get a plot without any color and the following warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Does anyone has any clue what is possibly going wrong?

Comment: I ran your code with the data your provided. This results in a plot with colours, and zero warnings. I suggest there is a problem with your input data.

Comment: I know the code works fine, but I don't know what I should be checking in my input data to stop this warning message and get a plot with colors. Do you know what causes this problem? Its a huge file with more than 3000 entries. What exactly should I be checking in it?

Comment: To be more specific, here is the actual file [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39515687/topic_word_matrix.data) which throws this warning

Comment: check for exmpla str(lda), check for NAs, ...

Comment: Sounds like some of your values are missing -- check for empty fields (i.e. ,,) in your input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error result from the Argument 'scale = "columns"'.

Your columns have a standard-deviation of 0, therefore scaling (mean / sd) fails.
So either use scale = "row" or scale = "none" or think why do you want to scale on columns.

HTH